# Not working expression

Tags: mysql, yii

Yii!
Please tell me, why this expreesion return 0 records, although database contains data matching this request.

```
$soldStatus = array('STATUS'=>'Sold','SELLER' => Yii::app()->user->id);
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array('order'=>'DATE_SALE DESC'));

$startDate = new CDbExpression("NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH");
$stopDate = new CDbExpression("NOW()");

$criteria->addBetweenCondition('DATE_SALE', $startDate, $stopDate);
$allSoldProducts = Products::model()->findAllByAttributes($soldStatus, $criteria);
```

Comment: Have you tried not "wrapping" attributes to CDbCriteria?

Comment: but `$criteria->condition = "DATE_SALE > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH";` is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the CDbExpressions - they are objects, and you try to set them into a funcion where values are needed.
[addBetweenCondition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addBetweenCondition-detail)

It expects 2 strings and you give it 2 expression objects.
I would change it to this:

```
$soldStatus = array('STATUS'=>'Sold','SELLER' => Yii::app()->user->id);
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array('order'=>'DATE_SALE DESC'));

$criteria->addBetweenCondition('DATE_SALE', "NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH", "NOW()");
$allSoldProducts = Products::model()->findAllByAttributes($soldStatus, $criteria);
```